# Is it possible to define references in a loop without array

Tags: php, reference

im trying to make a reference to a multidimentional array columns, 
and i need to make an $i ammount of references to the array values as string.
for example 1st row:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($array[0][column[$i]]);$i++)
{
   $value_1 = &$array[0][column[$i]];
}
```

is there a way to name the "$value_x" variable with $i identificator?
similar to `echo "$value_$i";`
im lacking experience with references, any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: You can set multiple variables with a name based on the loop index with `${"value_$i"}` -- https://3v4l.org/VYEqF :)

Comment: yes, this worked, never knew about the {}. would mark it an an answer.

Comment: Using `variable variables` (that is how they are called) will make your code harder to diagnose in the long run. Therefor wont recommend the usage of it especially because you don't know the specific size of `$array[0][column[$i]]` So does `$value_21` exist or not?

Comment: its for adding a bind param statement to the query, the $i is measured by the ammount of columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set multiple variables with a name based on the loop index with `${"value_$i"}`:

```
<?php

for ($i=0; $i<10;$i++)
{
   ${"value_$i"} = &$array[0][column[$i]];
}
```

I've created a working example showcasing this [here](http://3v4l.org/VYEqF) :)